# Image insertion in wrong excel sheet?

Tags: android, excel, apache-poi

I am creating an excel file using poi api. It runs fine and creates xls file. It inserts the pictures in the right sheet almost 99% times but 1% times it inserts images that are intended for other sheet in some another sheet.

This is a kinda 'Intermittent Bug', I can not even debug it manually because I do not know when it would appear next. But this bug is replacing images in the other excel sheet.

I am using different Patriach Classes for every sheet but not getting it if it is a bug of my code or api sometimes writes it to  another sheet?

Comment: Do your files already have images in them? And have you tried with Apache POI 3.9? (It has some relevant fixes)

Comment: I am using poi 3.7 for android. 

and yea I already have images in my worksheet.
Though I will try it with poi 3.9
Thanks.

Comment: POI 3.7 only supported adding pictures/drawings to files without any, adding to files with existing ones broke things. Try with 3.9

Comment: I have tried poi 3.9, I think I need to use supported libs with it. In poi 3.7 I was not having any crash in application but with poi 3.9 my app crashes with pictures in the attachment. 

It shows NoClassFoundEx because of commons-codec-1.5.jar. Now I imported it too in my project and still facing problems.

Comment: Now I succeeded in creating excel file using poi 3.9 and commons-codec-1.5.jar as a support library in the same package. 

Now all images are coming in the sheets but previous images are no being replaced by new images that I capture using my app, rather than these new images have been inserted over already existed images.

Comment: Hey!! poi 3.9 do not images in the template excel sheet. It is a fix they have done in this api version. 

Big relief to the size of the template, now we do not need to place dummy images in the template file.

Answer (score 0):

Promoting a comment to an answer...

Apache POI 3.7 only supported adding pictures/drawings to files without any, adding to files with existing ones broke things.

There was quite a bit of work on images in HSSF done for Apache POI 3.9 by Evgeniy Berlog as part of [GSOC](http://www.google-melange.com/gsoc/proposal/review/google/gsoc2012/evgeniy44/1). If you upgrade to POI 3.9, you should be able to add new images to a file which already has them.